# how can i convert str to float (the value of foreignkey)

Tags: python, django, math, operation

please how can i convert Foreignkey value string to float ? in models.py i create a following code, the target is to get the value of foreingkey as float then use it to calculate the value of redevance.

```
class periode_1(models.Model):
periode = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(4)], blank=True, null=True)
choix_taxe = (
    ('','taux periode recherche'),
    ('7000','7000'),('0','0'),)
taxe = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='', blank=False, null=True, choices=choix_taxe)
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.taxe) if self.taxe else ''


class tsf(models.Model):
    perimetre = models.FloatField(blank=False, null=True)
    production_tsf = models.ForeignKey(production, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=False)
    tsf_periode_1 = models.ForeignKey(periode_1, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=False)
    tsf_periode_2 = models.ForeignKey(periode_2, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    tsf_periode_3 = models.ForeignKey(periode_3, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    tsf_periode_4 = models.ForeignKey(periode_4, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.perimetre) if self.perimetre else ''

def calcule_tsf(self):
    return self.perimetre * (self.production_tsf_1.taxe + self.production_tsf_2.taxe + self.production_tsf_3.taxe + self.production_tsf_4.taxe)
```

the error seems like this:

enter image description here

thanks

Comment: Please only use relevant tags. I've removed the irrelevant [tag:javascript] tag.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please **do not** upload images of code / errors, add them as text formatted as code. See [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Also what exactly are you trying to do here?? Subtracting a foreign key?? Perhaps you want to subtract `quantite` or `prix` instead? Something like `- self.production_projet.quantite` or `- self.production_projet.prix`?

Comment: i wanna substract bouth value (self.production_projet.prix * self.production_projet.quantite)

Comment: Then why don't you simply write that there?...

Comment: precisely it displays an error

Comment: By the above comment I mean `return (self.cout_transport + self.cout_liquifaction + self.cout_separation) - (self.production_projet.prix * self.production_projet.quantite)` or `return (self.cout_transport + self.cout_liquifaction + self.cout_separation) - self.production_projet.calcule_production()`...

Comment: the above is for this result: return return (self.cout_transport + self.cout_liquifaction + self.cout_separation) - (self.production_projet.prix * self.production_projet.quantite)

Comment: please, get look on this, when i change the type of Field choices, i can't do the privious operation